# Comparability of variance estimation of residuals of WLS solutions

Tags: regression, least-squares, heteroscedasticity, weighted-regression, generalized-least-squares

I have a linear regression model with $p$ parameters

$$ y = X \beta + \varepsilon $$

and multiple datasets for the same model $y_i \in \mathbb{R}^N$ with known weights for each data point $w_i \in \mathbb{R}^N$ , $i=1,\dots,n$. I want to find the dataset which produces the minimum (estimated) variance of residuals. If all the weights were the same, i.e. $w_i = [1 ~~ \dots ~~ 1]^T, \forall i$, then we could use the formula

$$ \min_i \frac{\varepsilon_i^T \varepsilon_i}{N-p} = \min_i \frac{(y_i - X\hat{\beta}_i)^T (y_i - X\hat{\beta}_i)}{N-p} = \min_i \frac{y_i^T (I - X (X^T X)^{-1} X^T) y_i}{N-p}$$

Since there are known weights we can transform the WLS model of each dataset to OLS as

$$ \tilde{y}_i = \tilde{X}_i \beta_i + \tilde{\varepsilon}_i $$

where $\tilde{y}_i := W_i y_i, \tilde{X}_i := W_i X, \tilde{\varepsilon}_i := W_i \varepsilon$ and $W_i := \operatorname{diag}\{w_i\}$. So, the formula becomes

$$\min_i \frac{y_i^T W_i \left( I - W_i X (X^T W_i^2 X)^{-1} X^T W_i \right) W_i y_i}{N-p}$$

But now it seems wrong to compare the results with each other since the value of $w_i$ affects the comparability and needs to be adjusted. Indeed, if I use $\alpha w_i$ for one of the datasets where $\alpha$ is a scalar, then the variance estimation would be different by a factor of $\alpha^2$.

So, my question is how should I adjust the formula so I get comparable results between datasets? Is requiring $\lVert w_i \rVert = 1$ is enough and if so, why?

Comment: You should be comparing $|\hat \varepsilon_i|^2 / \text{var}( \varepsilon_i)$. Note that $\text{var}( \varepsilon_i) = w_i^2  \text{var}( \varepsilon).$